# Can objects names be used to create an instance of that object?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

So i'm learning to code in javascript, and right now i have a practice example of inheritance by prototype. The thing is, i have to achieve something like this:

```
var human = {}
var worker = human.create()
var dev = worker.create()

var adrian = dev.create("Adrian",28,20000)
```

The two points in the excercise go as follow:
1) To get rid of `Object.create`
2) To get rid of properties assignations Ex: `adrian.age = 28;`

I already know how to somehow do this on the "Classical Model" but im at a loss as to how to use my object name along with `.create`

I thought about creating a `constructor` function and use that to create an instance, but the result is undefined, because i don't have an object created to begin with

Comment: The example as posted will not work; objects don't have a "create" property.

Comment: That is not true. It can work. See my post below.
@Adrian: Did either of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your task actually is. It could be the following:

## Learning to work with Prototypes

Although the `.create` method does not exist on a plain object you could make it available.

Try starting by outputting the object itself:

```
Object.prototype.create = function(){
  console.log('Hello I am the object itself', this);
};

({foo: 'bar'}).create();
```

Then you could take this and think of how to actually make a copy of that. E.g. by using:

```
Object.prototype.create = function(){
  return Object.assign({}, this); // shallow copy
};

const human = {name: 'Max'};
const worker = human.create();
```

By this you basically created a shallow fork of human with your `worker`. Now if you want to go one step further -> just parametrize your function to take some arguments and add more props to your newly created object.

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript you write your constructor as a function. So to write a constructor function for a human, you would write:

```js
function human(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

const adrian = new human("Adrian", 28);

console.log(adrian.name, adrian.age); // prints the objects properties

console.log(JSON.stringify(adrian)); // prints the created object as json string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you may understand (maybe it's helpful):

```
function Human() {
  this.showName = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

var human = new Human();

function Worker() {
  this.showAge = function() {
    console.log(this.age);
  }
}

Worker.prototype = human;
var worker = new Worker();


function Dev(name, age, year) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.year = year;

  this.showYear = function() {
    console.log(this.year);
  }
}
Dev.prototype = worker;

var adrian = new Dev('Adrian', 28, 2000);

adrian.showAge(); // 28
adrian.showName(); // 'Adrian'
adrian.showYear(); // 2000
```

You can create instances of objects by calling the constructor. The constructor is a simple function (`Human`, `Worker`, `Dev`).

Every object you create (either by calling the constructor or not) has a special property called `prototype`. It can be set explicitly by setting the constructor's `prototype` property and it is the object from which inherits. In JavaScript objects inherit from other objects.

In this example `adrian`'s prototype is `worker`.

The process can be chained, so `worker`'s prototype is `human`.

Comment: Yes, this is the way i actually started, making a function to be my "class" and assigning the prototypes to each "subclass". But then i moved to the prototypal model inheritance, and i came to this point. Maybe the point in the exercise just wasn't clear enough or is just wrong.